# How Was the Sound of the Nazgûl Composed?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, behind-the-scenes, nazgul, sound-effects

Yes, yes, I am a complete freak. I think the screech/scream of the Nazgûl is both AWESOME and terrifying at the same time. I love it even though it makes me shiver!

**How was the sound of the Nazgûl composed? What sound effects or samples went into creating the final version of the Nazgûl's scream?**

For example, the movie *Twister* uses numerous combined samples to create the sound of the tornadoes. The noise in *Law and Order* (the *BUH-BUH* sound; surely anyone who's seen L&O knows which sound I'm referring to) The Nazgûl's scream has a very metallic sound to me; I'd love to know how it was created.

Comment: I'm a sound effect geek myself, actually. :)

Comment: Is this perhaps more appropriate for [movies.se]?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about movie sound effects.

Comment: @Richard behind-the-scenes production questions are on topic.
http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/620/22254
http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/2945/22254
http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/356/22254

Comment: @Moogle - Thank you for pointing this out and providing the supporting links. Of course this behind-the-scenes production is on topic. Appreciate it :)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r4BHDAYssfE

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Its actually Peter Jackson's wife, Fran Walsh, screeching, layered with the sound of a horse orgasm and if I remember right, a pig squealing. I never thought I'd type that sentence...

Seriously, he talks about it in the special features of the Fellowship of the Ring Extended edition, the name of the documentary is "Soundscapes of Middle Earth," IIRC.

For reference: [short clip of the scream](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k3VtzMxmPs0)

Comment: ... and an additional +1 to Peter Jackson for creative use of a spouse.

Comment: Not sure about the modulated, mixed in sounds indicated in this answer, but other sources indicate it was Fran Walsh (Jackson) as well. Man ... would hate to make her angry on a Sunday morning. For reference: [short clip of the scream](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k3VtzMxmPs0)

Comment: Maybe modulated is the wrong word. Layered is probably better.

Comment: I never thought I'd *ask* the question to elicit that trio of sound effects as an answer! I don't know what else to say except +1 :)

Comment: @Josh And creative use of a horse orgasm.

Comment: apparently there's a joke behind saying it was the sound she made when told they'd be making a Silmarillion movie next